# How can I style a JavaFX SplitMenuButton in CSS

Tags: css, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8, fxml

I try to style a SplitMenuButton in JavaFX. I've got a menuButton and a SplitMenuButton in my fxml-file.

My CSS-File looks like this:

```
.menu-button {
    -fx-background-color: red;
    }

.split-menu-button .label {
    -fx-background-color: green;
    }

.split-menu-button .arrow {
    -fx-background-color: yellow;
    }
```

But I can't figure out how to style the area around the arrow for the SplitMenuButton. I tried several ways, but nothing worked

```
.split-menu-button .menu-button {
    -fx-background-color: blue;
    }

.split-menu-button .menu-button .label {
    -fx-background-color: blue;
    }

.split-menu-button .menu{
    -fx-background-color: blue;
    }

.split-menu-button .menu-item {
    -fx-background-color: blue;
    }

.split-menu-button .button {
    -fx-background-color: blue;
    }

.split-menu-button .menu-bar {
    -fx-background-color: blue;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two useful techniques for figuring out the style classes for individual parts of complex components like this:

1. Extract the default style sheet, modena.css, from the jfxrt.jar file and see how the default styles are defined (you can also find [modena.css](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8/master/rt/file/f89b7dc932af/modules/controls/src/main/resources/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/modena/modena.css) online)
2. Use [ScenicView](http://fxexperience.com/scenic-view/) to inspect your application when it's running

In this case I used ScenicView; the css you need is

```
.split-menu-button .arrow-button {
    -fx-background-color: yellow ;
}
```